# Generate Excel file from DataTable (Best way), Interop

Tags: c#, datatable, interop

I want to generate an Excel file from DataTable in C#. Right now, I do a query on the database and it returns about 4 millions records. I already have reduced the time to 2 minutes; I don't want lose that optimization. Is there something like a "bulk" to write on a file? Everybody suggest to read row by row from DataSet and write on an Excel File.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/), I've used it in multiple projects and it meets my needs. If you take advantage of that an P-LINQ maybe you can achieve what you need.